# while after converting string to int

Tags: java, android, while-loop

I have a couple of string variables and I'm trying to put them into a while clause after I've converted them to integers.

Actual code below:

```
public void setUp()
    {
        String HText = "";
        int CorrectAnswer = Integer.parseInt(Levels.CorrectAnswer);
        int Question1 = Integer.parseInt(Levels.Question1);
        int Remaining = CorrectAnswer - Question1;
        TextView TVHint = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hint);
        //HintText.setText(String.valueOf(Remaining));
        /*while (Remaining != 0)
        {*/
            if (Remaining >= 100)
            {
                Remaining = Remaining - 100;
                if (HText != "")
                {
                    HText = HText + " + " + "100";
                }
                else
                {
                    HText = "100";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Remaining >= 10)
                {
                    Remaining = Remaining - 10;
                    if (HText != "")
                    {
                        HText = HText + " + " + "10";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HText = "10";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Remaining >= 5)
                    {
                        Remaining = Remaining - 5;
                        if (HText != "")
                        {
                            HText = HText + " + " + "5";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            HText = "5";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Remaining >= 1)
                        {
                            Remaining--;
                            if (HText != "")
                            {
                                HText = HText + " + " + "1";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                HText = "1";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        //}
        TVHint.setText(HText);
    }
```

This code will work but I want it to repeat until Remaining is 0 and the while commented out doesn't currently work.

Comment: post error code please

Comment: ***always fails on the while*** how does it fail???

Comment: Integer.parseInt(var1)

Comment: I've decided to show all the code in question. See above!

Comment: If my answer seems useful please give an up vote. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure `Levels.CorrectAnswer` and `Levels.Question1` contains valid string of `integer` value.

   > For example:
   >
   > `Levels.CorrectAnswer` value is `"110"` and `Levels.Question1` value
   >   is `"1"`
2. Use `Math.abs(CorrectAnswer - Question1)` to get absolute `Remaining` value.

   > ```
   > int Remaining = Math.abs(CorrectAnswer - Question1);
   > ```
3. Add some `logs` to check the value of `Remaining` and `HText`.

**Here is the working code:**

```
public void setUp()
{
    Levels Levels = new Levels();

    String HText = "";
    int CorrectAnswer = Integer.parseInt(Levels.CorrectAnswer);
    int Question1 = Integer.parseInt(Levels.Question1);
    int Remaining = CorrectAnswer - Question1;

    Log.d("setUp", "CorrectAnswer: " + CorrectAnswer + "\n"
            + "Question1: " + Question1 + "\n" + "Remaining: " + Remaining);

    TextView TVHint = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hint);
    while (Remaining != 0)
    {
        Log.d("setUp", "Remaining: " + Remaining);
        if (Remaining >= 100)
        {
            Remaining = Remaining - 100;
            Log.d("setUp", "Remaining - 100: " + Remaining);

            if (HText != "")
            {
                HText = HText + " + " + "100";
            }
            else
            {
                HText = "100";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Remaining >= 10)
            {
                Remaining = Remaining - 10;
                Log.d("setUp", "Remaining - 10: " + Remaining);

                if (HText != "")
                {
                    HText = HText + " + " + "10";
                }
                else
                {
                    HText = "10";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Remaining >= 5)
                {
                    Remaining = Remaining - 5;
                    Log.d("setUp", "Remaining - 5: " + Remaining);

                    if (HText != "")
                    {
                        HText = HText + " + " + "5";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HText = "5";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Remaining >= 1)
                    {
                        Remaining--;
                        Log.d("setUp", "Remaining - 1: " + Remaining);

                        if (HText != "")
                        {
                            HText = HText + " + " + "1";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            HText = "1";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d("setUp", "HText: " + HText);
    }
    TVHint.setText(HText);
}
```

**OUTPUT LOG:**

```
04-18 20:39:52.634 23432-23432/com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/setUp: CorrectAnswer: 110
                                                                        Question1: 1
                                                                        Remaining: 109
04-18 20:39:52.634 23432-23432/com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/setUp: Remaining: 109
04-18 20:39:52.634 23432-23432/com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/setUp: Remaining - 100: 9
04-18 20:39:52.634 23432-23432/com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/setUp: HText: 100
04-18 20:39:52.634 23432-23432/com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/setUp: Remaining: 9
04-18 20:39:52.634 23432-23432/com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/setUp: Remaining - 5: 4
04-18 20:39:52.634 23432-23432/com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/setUp: HText: 100 + 5
04-18 20:39:52.634 23432-23432/com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/setUp: Remaining: 4
04-18 20:39:52.634 23432-23432/com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/setUp: Remaining - 1: 3
04-18 20:39:52.634 23432-23432/com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/setUp: HText: 100 + 5 + 1
04-18 20:39:52.634 23432-23432/com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/setUp: Remaining: 3
04-18 20:39:52.634 23432-23432/com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/setUp: Remaining - 1: 2
04-18 20:39:52.634 23432-23432/com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/setUp: HText: 100 + 5 + 1 + 1
04-18 20:39:52.634 23432-23432/com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/setUp: Remaining: 2
04-18 20:39:52.634 23432-23432/com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/setUp: Remaining - 1: 1
04-18 20:39:52.634 23432-23432/com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/setUp: HText: 100 + 5 + 1 + 1 + 1
04-18 20:39:52.634 23432-23432/com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/setUp: Remaining: 1
04-18 20:39:52.634 23432-23432/com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/setUp: Remaining - 1: 0
04-18 20:39:52.634 23432-23432/com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/setUp: HText: 100 + 5 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: ive got it decreasing in my code, its just an example but didn't put that part in.

Comment: @TomBrad95 what is the value of Levels.CorrectAnswer and Levels.Question1

Comment: @TomBrad95 check my updated answer. Hope this will help you

Comment: @TomBrad95 Thanks for marked it as right answer. If my answer seems usefule please give an upvote. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try `Integer.parseInt(var1)` instead.

Comment: If you run the program, the issue is not because of `int var1Int = Integer.valueOf(var1);` line, there is an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Your program goes in an Infinite loop. Because you are setting the value of `var1Int` to be equal to 1 and in the `while` loop the condition is

```
while (var1Int != 0)
```

i.e . it will come out of the loop when `var1Int` becomes equal to 0 which never happens because the value of loop variable `var1Int` is not changing. Hence the loop keeps on executing infinitely. You should write code to change the value of `var1Int` so that exit condition is met.
For example, you can try this

```
String var1 = "1";
int var1Int = Integer.valueOf(var1);
while (var1Int != 0)
{
var1Int --;
}
```

This will make `var1Int` value equal to 0 which is the terminating condition, it will come out of the loop.This is just an example, You can write the logic based on your requirement.
The issue is not because of Parsing the `String` to `int`. If it was the case it would have given error at the following line only.

```
int var1Int = Integer.valueOf(var1);
```

Comment: ive got it decreasing in my code, its just an example but didn't put that part in.

Answer (score 0):

It does not fail,the loop works fine,since it is infinite loop it will go on 'forever',try to print out something and you will see.

If you want to break out from it just decrement your value and eventually it will reach 0:

```
while(a != 0){
  System.out.println(var1Int);//so you can check the difference
  var1Int--;
}
```

Comment: ive got it decreasing in my code, its just an example but didn't put that part in.

Comment: Try to be more precise and give more detail about the actual problem.